# try-catch on WebException not working

Tags: c#, try-catch, getresponsestream

i have problem With HttpWebRequest.getResponse(). My try catch don't catch my response :/. Here is code:
*proxy and ports are good*

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
        req.Proxy = new WebProxy(Host, Port);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Timeout = 10000;
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";

      try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {

                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException) { }
        catch (Exception){ }
```

Still getting window with error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MriAT.jpg

Comment: What do you want to happen? What's the error message in English?

Comment: The default connection has been closed. An unexpeced error occured while collecting.
I want to check if proxy is working. Last time without threding this worked perfect now cant try and catch errors.
However sometime i will get 404 exception or another one :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your try/catch *is* catching your exception; however, execution is breaking because you have first-chance exception debugging enabled. If you press "Continue", your program will proceed as expected. To alter this behaviour, just click the "Debug" menu, "Exceptions...", and untick the "Thrown" checkbox for CLR exceptions.

[image]